# create single shipment using FedEx api for mutiple packages

Tags: node.js, fedex

We are trying to implement fedEx shipment apis using 'node-shipping-fedex'. We need to create **single shipment** for multiple package.

We haved tried it by adding **multiple package** inside RequestedPackageLineItems. Got following error.

**Error: The number of RequestedPackages in the RequestedShipment must be equal to 1
Error code - 2463**

Any help on this highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd need more information (like perhaps a section of your current code that isn't working) to be much more helpful, but have you tried altering PackageCount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FedEx API does not support multiple packages in a shipment reqest. Each box is a separate API call. The first one gets sent stating that it's multi-box. You then pass the track# from the first package with the subsequent shipments so they are tied together.